# Why does importing `apple-mapkit-js` fail using Storybook with Vite and Vue2?

Tags: vue.js, vite, storybook

I have a simple Vue component that imports `apple-mapkit-js`.

```
<template>
  <div />
</template>

<script>
import "apple-mapkit-js";

export default {
  name: "AppleMapKitMap",
};
</script>
```

I also have a simple stories file that attempts to render this component.

```
import AppleMapKitMap from "./AppleMapKitMap.vue";

export default {
  component: "AppleMapKitMap",
};

const Template = (args) => ({
  components: {
    AppleMapKitMap,
  },

  setup: () => ({ args }),

  template: `<AppleMapKitMap />`,
});

export const Primary = Template.bind({});
```

Something (either Vite or Storybook) is choking on the `apple-mapkit-js` import.

In the browser I get the following errors:

```
Loading module from “http://localhost:51920/node_modules/.cache/sb-vite/deps/apple-mapkit-js.js?v=e946ea77” was blocked because of a disallowed MIME type (“text/html”). iframe.html
```

```
TypeError: error loading dynamically imported module: http://localhost:51920/src/components/AppleMapKitMap.stories.js?t=1703096715798 runtime.js:4:96581
```

And in my terminal (running `npm run storybook`) I get the following errors:

```
[vite] Internal server error: Failed to resolve import "xmlhttprequest" from "node_modules\.cache\sb-vite\deps\apple-mapkit-js.js?v=e946ea77". Does the file exist?
  Plugin: vite:import-analysis
  File: C:/Users/chris/Documents/GitHub/brokerage-website-components/node_modules/.cache/sb-vite/deps/apple-mapkit-js.js?v=e946ea77:1:45
  1  |  import * as __require_for_vite_H6WARN from "xmlhttprequest";
     |                                              ^
  2  |  import * as __require_for_vite_DaMaKl from "url";
  3  |  import * as __require_for_vite_VW7xZn from "xmlhttprequest";
      at formatError (file:///C:/Users/chris/Documents/GitHub/brokerage-website-components/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-2faf2534.js:40358:46)        
      at TransformContext.error (file:///C:/Users/chris/Documents/GitHub/brokerage-website-components/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-2faf2534.js:40354:19)
      at normalizeUrl (file:///C:/Users/chris/Documents/GitHub/brokerage-website-components/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-2faf2534.js:37222:33)       
      at async TransformContext.transform (file:///C:/Users/chris/Documents/GitHub/brokerage-website-components/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-2faf2534.js:37355:47)
      at async Object.transform (file:///C:/Users/chris/Documents/GitHub/brokerage-website-components/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-2faf2534.js:40611:30)
      at async loadAndTransform (file:///C:/Users/chris/Documents/GitHub/brokerage-website-components/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-2faf2534.js:36998:29)
```

Here is my `vite.config.js`

```
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import vue from "@vitejs/plugin-vue";
import { resolve } from "path";
import { viteCommonjs } from '@originjs/vite-plugin-commonjs';

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    vue(),
    viteCommonjs(),
  ],
  build: {
    lib: {
      entry: resolve(__dirname, "src/components.js"),
      name: "[REDACTED]",
      fileName: "[REDACTED]",
    },
    rollupOptions: {
      external: ["vue", "inputmask/dist/inputmask.es6"],
      output: {
        globals: {
          vue: "Vue",
        },
      },
    },
  },
});
```

Not sure if this is an issue with Vite or with Storybook. Seems like it could be either or and the Googling I have done hasn't proved helpful.